# Create and Download Zip File in PHP

Tags: php, zip

I have migrated a LAMP (Linux Apache MySql PHP) system from a physical server to a virtual machine (clean install, not a physical-to-virtual transfer).  On the old machine, the following code would search in the orders directory for all $jid.csv files, create a zip file and then prompt the user to download the zip file.  On the new machine, the zip file is not created, instead the user is prompted to download a zip file of 0 bytes.  Apache can write to this folder, as the same PHP script is also creating the CSV files mentioned earlier.

Script that is failing:

```
else if($loops>1) {
    header("Content-Type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$jid.zip");
    system("cd orders;zip $jid.zip $jid-*.csv > /dev/null");
    $myFile = "orders/$jid.zip";
    readfile("orders/$jid.zip");
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked error logs for anything eluding to this? You're sure that `zip` is installed? `cd orders` we're sure that the execution of this script calls the orders directory from within the same path?

Comment: The orders folder is inside of the apache root directory.  The script writes the CSV files to the orders folder, so I think the path is correct.  (httpd/error_log reporting: sh: zip: command not found).  Must be zip extension not installed...

Comment: There's your issue. Zip isn't installed on the server, and it looks like debian. Let's install it! `sudo apt-get update`, then `sudo apt-get install zip`

Comment: That was it!  php -m was listing zip as an installed module, but zip was not actually installed on the machine.  It is a Centos machine, so yum install zip worked!  Thank you!

Comment: Ah, centos as opposed to debian. Glad we could get that sorted. Best of luck, friend.

Comment: just out of curiosity, is there a way to write a zip file using just PHP (as in, no system commands)?

Comment: You may want to look here:  http://php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php